# What does 'OP' mean?

Tags: discussion, terminology

In many comments, I have seen the word 'OP', and I have inferred that this refers to the asker of the question. What I want to know is why OP means what it does. Is it an abbreviation? Is it just called that because someone started calling it that?

Comment: See the glossary on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/285368

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It stands for "Original Poster". A possibly more accurate term on our site might be "asker", but this is a carryover from other sites that have a forum structure.

Comment: I thought it was opening poster but I guess they mean the same.

Comment: It can also mean Overpowered.

Comment: I know this isn't correct in the context of this question, but "op" can also refer to an admin on a multiplayer server, which in this instance would be short for "operator"

Comment: In that context it's the same as SysAdmin

Comment: Sometimes OP is also referred to as [**Original Post**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum#Post).

Answer (score 14):

There are various contexts for "OP", to be honest...
The most common context is Original Poster, in this way it's used on forums.

The most popular is OverPowered, in which it's used to describe something that's just THAT powerful... like the BFG 9000 in Doom.

The last, that I know of, is OPerator, used on multiplayer games to denote admins, moderators, or the server owner. This context is, undeniably, the most powerful, as such people could easily ban you for doing dumb things, like griefing, trolling or hacking.