# How do OP cards exist in meta but not in main site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, users, user-card

When I asked [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/404905/do-opponents-die-if-you-dont-perform-a-fatality?noredirect=1#comment568523_404905) question I didn't have an OP card and my comment also didn't have it:

[image: opcard1]

But in meta posts like [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11482/what-does-op-mean) the OP cards exist:

[image: opcard2]

In comments:

[image: opcard3]

[image: opcard4]

Why is there this difference between our meta and main sites?

I'm not sure if it's a bug. Feel free to remove the tag if it's wrong.

Comment: Are you talking about the highlight or background colour of the OP's name in comments?

Comment: @Joachim Yes, both in comments and in the posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**
[This appears to have been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394232/update-new-colors-launched):

[image: image showing OP cards]

---

This is a known [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393956/342074).

Network wide, Stack Exchange [implemented new colors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched), and it seems this is one of the many bugs (not all sites exhibit this bug though).  It looks like it has been identified and is expected to be fixed in a future update.